# What is the main reason for Android 2.x browser issues (e.g. CSS support)?

Tags: android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-browser, android-2.1-eclair

Android Browser on 2.x has some issues such as icon font support and partial support for CSS animations among other things. Is this more of a Webkit 533.1 issue (which is the Webkit version used by Android 2.x) or an operating system issue?